# TikZ's decoration option for paths derails pgfplots axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Well, the title says it all: TikZ's decoration option for paths derails pgfplots axis' formatting. Included in the MWE is my whole preamble concerning TikZ. If I run the MWE below, I get the following output but I'd rather not uncomment the `decoration={brace}` line. If I leave it in, it looks like this:

[image: abc]

So, is there a solution to this with `decoration={brace}` staying active? Or did I make some error?

[datadump](http://pastebin.com/ZnfmFJVT)

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[
a4paper
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{
tikz,
pgfplots,
amsmath
}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{
lmodern,
textcomp
}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,trees,shadows,positioning,arrows,chains,shapes.geometric,%
    decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes,%
    matrix,shapes.symbols,patterns,intersections}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background layer}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground layer}
\pgfsetlayers{background layer,main,foreground layer}

\tikzset{
>=open triangle 45,
  line/.style={draw, thick, ->},
  kapitel/.style={
    node distance=0.8cm,
        rectangle,
        drop shadow={opacity=0.5},
        minimum width=4em,
        minimum height=4em,
        text width=12em,
    font=\sffamily\bfseries,
    draw={black!80, very thick},
        fill=black!40,
        %top color=white,
    %bottom color=white!20!blue,    
    on chain},
  every join/.style={->, thick, shorten >=1pt},
    abschnitt/.style={
    node distance=0.5cm,
        rectangle,
        drop shadow={opacity=0.5},
    rounded corners, 
        minimum height=2em, 
        minimum width=4em,
        text width=10em,
    draw=black!80,
        fill=black!20,
        %shade,
    font=\sffamily,
        %top color=white!80!black,
        %bottom color=white,
    %text centered,
    on chain},
  decoration={brace},
}



\def\parsedate#1-#2!{%
    \pgfmathparse{#1+1/12*(1#2-101)}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width=14cm, height=8cm,
    axis lines*=left,
    ymin=0,
    enlargelimits=upper,
    /pgf/number format/1000 sep={},
    x coord trafo/.code={\expandafter\parsedate#1!}
]
\addplot [no markers] table [col sep=semicolon] {datadump.csv};%\datatable};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do you want to have the decoration active globally?

Comment: Another question: why do you want to add the brace _on_ the axis? Can not you just use it outside the axis if the purpose is to group some data?

Comment: Here is a _hack_ solution: Add `axis line style={decoration={amplitude=0pt}}` option to the `axis`.

Comment: I just used [an example](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/assignment-structure/) and amended it a bit to my needs.  @PeterGrill Thank you, I now realized I can edit it a lot more, I wasn't that experienced (still am not) when I used the example's code first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable the decoration locally by setting `decoration={name=none}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[
a4paper
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{
tikz,
pgfplots,
amsmath
}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{
lmodern,
textcomp
}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,trees,shadows,positioning,arrows,chains,shapes.geometric,%
    decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes,%
    matrix,shapes.symbols,patterns,intersections}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background layer}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground layer}
\pgfsetlayers{background layer,main,foreground layer}

\tikzset{
>=open triangle 45,
  line/.style={draw, thick, ->},
  kapitel/.style={
    node distance=0.8cm,
        rectangle,
        drop shadow={opacity=0.5},
        minimum width=4em,
        minimum height=4em,
        text width=12em,
    font=\sffamily\bfseries,
    draw={black!80, very thick},
        fill=black!40,
        %top color=white,
    %bottom color=white!20!blue,    
    on chain},
  every join/.style={->, thick, shorten >=1pt},
    abschnitt/.style={
    node distance=0.5cm,
        rectangle,
        drop shadow={opacity=0.5},
    rounded corners, 
        minimum height=2em, 
        minimum width=4em,
        text width=10em,
    draw=black!80,
        fill=black!20,
        %shade,
    font=\sffamily,
        %top color=white!80!black,
        %bottom color=white,
    %text centered,
    on chain},
  decoration={brace},
}



\def\parsedate#1-#2!{%
    \pgfmathparse{#1+1/12*(1#2-101)}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    decoration={name=none},
    width=14cm, height=8cm,
    axis lines*=left,
    ymin=0,
    enlargelimits=upper,
]
\addplot [no markers]  {rnd};%\datatable};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```